# For loop not getting executed correctly over ssh

Tags: shell-script, ssh, quoting

I have a script in which I am reading from a csv file where it contains `SourceIp, DestinationIP,Source Ports, Destination Ports`.

First I am reading the sourceIp and trying to do ssh over it (I am able to do it successfully), here I am trying to get a pseudo terminal and want to execute a for loop that will iterate over the sourcePorts(hyphen separated) and destinationPorts.

**Input File Content :**

```
10.X.X.9,10.X.X.23,8140-61613,1521-1524-1525-1526-1530-1531-8140-61613
```

**Script :**

```
export lastSourceIP=""
export lastDestinationIP=""
export fqdn=""
export sourceFqdn=""
x=0
export username="sjain";
export location="/home/sjain/poc";
export baseLocation="10.X.X.9"
while IFS="," read f1 f2 f3 f4
do
        x=$(($x+1))
        TMP=$(mktemp)
        TMP2=$(mktemp)
        echo "Source IP        : $f1"       
        echo "Destination IP   : $f2"
        echo "Source Ports             : $f3"
        echo "Destination Ports             : $f4"
export sourceIP=$f1
export destIP=$(echo "$f2" | tr -d '\n')
export port=$(echo "$f3" | tr -d '\n')
export destinationPorts=$(echo "$f4" | tr -d '\n')
ssh -t -t $username@$sourceIP 'bash -s' <<ENDSSH
(IFS='-'; for sourceP in $port; do 
 (for destinationP in $destinationPorts; do
    echo "$sourceP" - "$destinationP"
 done;) 
done;)
exit 
ENDSSH

done < ipaddress.csv
```

But when I am executing this script , it is not printing sourceIP - DestinationIp values.
Here , is the output that I am getting on console.

**Output:**

```
    Source IP        : 10.X.X.9
    Destination IP   : 10.X.X.23
    Source Ports             : 8140-61613
    Destination Ports             : 1521-1524-1525-1526-1530-1531-8140-61613
    tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    (IFS='-'; for sourceP in 8140-61613; do
     (for destinationP in 1521-1524-1525-1526-1530-1531-8140-61613; do
        echo "" - ""
     done;)
    done;)
    exit
    [sjain@XXX.SERVER ~]$ (IFS='-'; for sourceP in 8140-61613; do
    >  (for destinationP in 1521-1524-1525-1526-1530-1531-8140-61613; do
    >     echo "" - ""
    >  done;)
    > done;)
     -
    [sjain@XXX.SERVER ~]$ exit
    exit
    Connection to 10.X.X.9 closed

.
```

**Expected Output :**

```
8140-1521
8140-1524
.... and so on
```

Please help where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to ensure the loop vars are derefenced on the remote host:

```
ssh -t -t $username@$sourceIP 'bash -s' <<ENDSSH
 IFS='-'
 for sourceP in $port; do 
  for destinationP in $destinationPorts; do
    echo "\$sourceP" - "\$destinationP"
  done 
 done
ENDSSH
```

Using all the parentheses launches a subshell for each loop iteration, which is a lot of extra work you don't need.

You don't need to export all your variables, only the ones that need to be in the environment for child processes.

This `destIP=$(echo "$f2" | tr -d '\n')` is no different from `destIP=$f2` -- assuming there are no "internal" newlines. `$(command substitution)` removes trailing newlines.

Comment: thanks glenn, i removed the parentheses and now it is printing the value , but it seems like that loop has not been executed properly (executed only once).It considered "8140-61613" and "1521-1524-1525-1526-1530-1531-8140-61613" as one string , I mean it didn't tokenize it using "-". This is output i got 
`8140-61613 - 1521-1524-1525-1526-1530-1531-8140-61613`. 
But I am expecting output in the format as I mentioned in the qns.

Comment: It seems like IFS is not overriding the value to "-".

Comment: Yes, that's true, because you're setting IFS on the remote host but substituting the variable locally. Do this: remove the IFS line and use `${port//-/ }` (same for the other var)

Comment: i tried this , but this time it removed the hyphen and collapsed all the values into one string like this.
`814061613 - 152115241525152615301531814061613`

Comment: make sure there's a space between the last slash and the close brace.